# Applications Not Showing Up in Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity

This has happened a couple of times now, the unity menu (when you click on the Ubuntu logo) has all the categories there but when you click on say media apps it will be blank the same for the other options as well. searching for something will also draw a blank =/

any help?

Using Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 2 32bit

Comment: I had the same experience but I had upgraded from kubuntu to Unity. Was it a clean installation?

Comment: Yep completely clean install of Beta 1 with all the updates

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug. As this is not normal behavior. Please report bugs in launchpad. You can report bugs specifically on unity [here](https://launchpad.net/unity).

Answer (score 1):

`$unity --reset`

worked for me.

I hope this help you.